# Как получить связанные сущности на даппере?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dapper

Есть запрос на Entity Framework, который вызывает таблицы из БД по Id другой таблицы

```
var result = this.Context.LiveEnquiryServices
        .Include("LiveService")
        .Include("LiveEnquirySection")
        .Include("LiveEnquiryDocuments")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.LiveEnquirySectionId == liveEnquirySectionId && x.LiveServiceId == serviceId);
return result;
```

Пытаюсь сделать тоже самое, только через Dapper, пока что выходит что-то такое

```
public List<LiveEnquiryService> GetLiveEnquiryServices(Enquiry enquiry)
{
    List<LiveEnquiryService> liveEnquiryService = new List<LiveEnquiryService>();

    var query = $"SELECT LiveService.*, LiveEnquirySection.*, LiveEnquiryDocuments.* FROM LiveEnquiryServices WHERE LiveEnquirySectionId = '{enquiry.Id}';";

    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        liveEnquiryService = db.Query<LiveEnquiryService, LiveService, LiveEnquirySection, List<LiveEnquiryServiceDocument>, LiveEnquiryService>(query, (les, ls, lesn, lesd) =>
        {
            les.LiveService = ls;
            les.LiveServiceId = ls.Id;
            les.LiveEnquirySection = lesn;
            les.LiveEnquirySectionId = lesn.Id;
            les.LiveEnquiryDocuments = lesd;
            //les.LiveEnquiryDocuments = lesd;
            return les;
        }, splitOn: "Id").ToList();

    }
    return liveEnquiryService.ToList();
}
```

Кто-то может подсказать, как доделать то, что пытаюсь сделать я?

Если вопрос не понятен или мало информации, пишите - буду дополнять.

Comment: Добавьте описания ваших сущностей в вопрос, гадать об устройстве не очень хочется. Подгрузка связанных сущностей один-к-одному у вас в правильном направлении, а подгрузка сущностей связанных как один-ко-многим вообще не так делается: см. Multiple Results в документации.

Answer (score 4):

Всё это есть на [заглавной странице репозитория на github](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Что хочется отметить сразу. Ваш вопрос распадается на два подвопроса:

- подгрузка связанных сущностей связанных отношением один-к-одному (в ваших примерах это `.Include(x => x.LiveService)` и `.Include(x => x.LiveEnquirySection)`
- подгрузка связанных сущностей связанных отношением один-ко-многим (в вашем вопросе это `.Include(x => x.LiveEnquiryDocuments)`)

Вот и рассмотрим его на моём примере (для того, чтобы рассматривать ваш - нужно представлять поля сущностей), другие примеры посмотрите в документации.

В базе у нас будет всего две сущности: Brand и Products.

```
public class Brand
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BrandID { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

#### Получение связанных сущностей один-к-одному:

Исходный linq-запрос:

```
this.Db.Product
       .Include(x => x.Brand)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToArray();
```

Код для dapper:

```
var sql = @"
    select *
    from Products p
    left join Brands b on b.ID = p.BrandID
    where 1 = 1
";

var data = this.Connection.Query<Product, Brand, Product>(sql, (p, b) =>
{
    p.Brand = b;
    return p;
});

return data.ToArray();
```

Кажется громоздким и непривычным? Лишь поначалу.

#### Получение связанных сущностей один-ко-многим:

Исходный linq-запрос имеет вид:

```
this.Db.Brand
       .Include(x => x.Products)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToArray();
```

К сожалению, dapper не очень хорошо умеет поддерживать подобную загрузку, поэтому воспользуемся возможностью подгрузки Multiple Results в одном запросе:

```
var sql = @"
    select
          b.ID
        , b.Name
    from Brands b
    where 1 = 1

    select
          p.ID
        , p.Name
        , p.BrandID
    from Products p
    where 1 = 1
";

using (var multi = this.Connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
{
    var brands = multi.Read<Brand>();
    var products = multi.Read<Product>();
    return brands.Select(x => new Brand
    {
        ID       = x.ID,
        Name     = x.Name,
        Products = products.Where(y => y.BrandID == x.ID).ToArray(),
    });
}
```