# Загрузка связанных данных EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется таблица Tickets, у которой несколько связей.
Чтобы загрузить все необходимые связанные данные, получается такой запрос:

```
var ticket = _db.Tickets
            .Include(t=>t.Group)
            .Include(t=>t.TicketContacts)
            .ThenInclude(t=>t.Contact)
            .Include(t=>t.TicketProducts)
            .ThenInclude(t=>t.Product)
            .Include(t=>t.AppUser)
            .Include(t => t.Status)
            .Include(t => t.Abonent)
            .Include(t=>t.Events)
            .ThenInclude(t=>t.Message)
            .ThenInclude(t=>t.Attachments)
            .Include(t => t.Events)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Message)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Contact)
            .Include(t=>t.Events)
            .ThenInclude(t=>t.User)
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
```

Настораживает большое количество include'ов. В бд будут отправляться несколько запросов.  Правильно ли я делаю, или можно как то это упростить ?

Как я понял (по окну Вывода), получаю 5 запросов:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Id], ...
FROM[Tickets] AS[t]
LEFT JOIN[Abonents] AS[t.Abonent] ON[t].[AbonentId] = [t.Abonent].[Id]
INNER JOIN[Statuses] AS[t.Status] ON[t].[StatusId] = [t.Status].[Id]
LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.AppUser] ON[t].[AppUserId] = [t.AppUser].[Id]
LEFT JOIN[Groups] AS[t.Group] ON[t].[GroupId] = [t.Group].[Id]
WHERE[t].[Id] = @__id_0
ORDER BY[t].[Id]

SELECT[t.TicketContacts].[TicketId], ...
FROM[TicketContacts] AS[t.TicketContacts]
INNER JOIN[Contacts] AS[t.Contact] ON[t.TicketContacts].[ContactId] =  [t.Contact].[Id]
INNER JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT [t1].*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [t0].[Id]
    FROM[Tickets] AS[t0]
    LEFT JOIN[Abonents] AS[t.Abonent0] ON[t0].[AbonentId] = [t.Abonent0].[Id]
    INNER JOIN[Statuses] AS[t.Status0] ON[t0].[StatusId] = [t.Status0].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.AppUser0] ON[t0].[AppUserId] = [t.AppUser0].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[Groups] AS[t.Group0] ON[t0].[GroupId] = [t.Group0].[Id]
    WHERE[t0].[Id] = @__id_0
    ORDER BY[t0].[Id]
) AS[t1]
) AS[t2] ON[t.TicketContacts].[TicketId] = [t2].[Id]
ORDER BY[t2].[Id]

SELECT[t.TicketProducts].[TicketId], ...
FROM[TicketProducts] AS[t.TicketProducts]
INNER JOIN[Products] AS[t.Product] ON[t.TicketProducts].[ProductId] = [t.Product].[Id]
INNER JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT [t4].*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [t3].[Id]
    FROM[Tickets] AS[t3]
    LEFT JOIN[Abonents] AS[t.Abonent1] ON[t3].[AbonentId] = [t.Abonent1].[Id]
    INNER JOIN[Statuses] AS[t.Status1] ON[t3].[StatusId] = [t.Status1].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.AppUser1] ON[t3].[AppUserId] = [t.AppUser1].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[Groups] AS[t.Group1] ON[t3].[GroupId] = [t.Group1].[Id]
    WHERE[t3].[Id] = @__id_0
    ORDER BY[t3].[Id]
) AS[t4]
) AS[t5] ON[t.TicketProducts].[TicketId] = [t5].[Id]
ORDER BY[t5].[Id]

SELECT[t.Events].[Id], ...
FROM[TicketEvents] AS[t.Events]
LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.User] ON[t.Events].[AppUserId] = [t.User].[Id]
LEFT JOIN[Messages] AS[t.Message] ON[t.Events].[MessageId] = [t.Message].[Id]
LEFT JOIN[Contacts] AS[t.Message.Contact] ON[t.Message].[ContactId] = [t.Message.Contact].[Id]
INNER JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT [t7].*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [t6].[Id]
    FROM[Tickets] AS[t6]
    LEFT JOIN[Abonents] AS[t.Abonent2] ON[t6].[AbonentId] = [t.Abonent2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN[Statuses] AS[t.Status2] ON[t6].[StatusId] = [t.Status2].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.AppUser2] ON[t6].[AppUserId] = [t.AppUser2].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN[Groups] AS[t.Group2] ON[t6].[GroupId] = [t.Group2].[Id]
    WHERE[t6].[Id] = @__id_0
    ORDER BY[t6].[Id]
) AS[t7]
) AS[t8] ON[t.Events].[TicketId] = [t8].[Id]
ORDER BY[t8].[Id], [t.Message].[Id]

SELECT[t.Message.Attachments].[Id], ...
FROM[Attachments] AS[t.Message.Attachments]
INNER JOIN(
SELECT DISTINCT [t.Message0].[Id], [t11].[Id] AS [Id0]
FROM[TicketEvents] AS [t.Events0]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS[t.User0] ON [t.Events0].[AppUserId] = [t.User0].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Messages] AS[t.Message0] ON [t.Events0].[MessageId] = [t.Message0].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Contacts] AS[t.Message.Contact0] ON [t.Message0].[ContactId] = [t.Message.Contact0].[Id]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t10].*
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(1) [t9].[Id]
        FROM[Tickets] AS[t9]
        LEFT JOIN[Abonents] AS[t.Abonent3] ON[t9].[AbonentId] = [t.Abonent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN[Statuses] AS[t.Status3] ON[t9].[StatusId] = [t.Status3].[Id]
        LEFT JOIN[AspNetUsers] AS[t.AppUser3] ON[t9].[AppUserId] = [t.AppUser3].[Id]
        LEFT JOIN[Groups] AS[t.Group3] ON[t9].[GroupId] = [t.Group3].[Id]
        WHERE[t9].[Id] = @__id_0
        ORDER BY[t9].[Id]
    ) AS[t10]
) AS[t11] ON[t.Events0].[TicketId] = [t11].[Id]
) AS[t12] ON[t.Message.Attachments].[MessageId] = [t12].[Id]
ORDER BY[t12].[Id0], [t12].[Id]
```

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что загнал данный пример в Linqpad и посмотрел бы итоговый запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё наоборот: `.Include()` требуются, чтобы уменьшить число запросов.

В классическом EF дело обстояло так. Если вы сначала получите список `Tickets`, потом попросите у БД `ticket.TicketContacts` и т.д., то выполнится два запроса: `SELECT * FROM Tickets` и `SELECT * FROM TicketContacts WHERE TICKET_ID = @ticketId` (условно)

Если же вызовете `Tickets.Include(t=>t.TicketContacts)`, то выполнится единственный запрос `SELECT T.*, G.* FROM Tickets T LEFT JOIN TicketContacts G ON G.TICKET_ID = T.ID` (опять же, условно. скорее всего будут перечислены поля и вообще)

В EF.Core, если мне не изменяет память, возможен только второй вариант: автоматическая ленивая загрузка не реализована.

Так что вы поступаете абсолютно правильно. Объединение таблиц - то, для чего созданы серверы реляционных БД, пусть они этим и занимаются.

UPD: В документации MS [написано](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data), что объединение в единственный запрос - фича EF Core 3, а в версии 2 могло отправиться несколько запросов. По той же ссылке рекомендован пакет, который включает ленивую загрузку в EF Core (но тогда точно запросов будет много).

Comment: В классическом EF тоже был Include: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php - в остальном же согласен (include уменьшает число запросов, в коре пока не всё реализовали)

Comment: @AK AFAIK ленивую загрузку не реализовали не "пока", a by design

Comment: Разве? Надо же, не знал, а можете подкинуть ссылку на подобную информацию? Вообще же, как по мне: да и хорошо, что не будут реализовывать, я всегда считал что этот режим для лентяев и от него только больше способов выстрелить себе в ногу, не понимая что пишешь неоптимальный код, который тебе будет сильно нагружать sql сервер.

Comment: Как я понял (по окну Вывода), я получаю пять запросов:

Comment: @AK читал когда-то в блоге, но сейчас не вспомню где.
Однако, я оказывается был неправ: поведение зависит от версии https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data . В старых могло быть несколько запросов, в новой один с кучей джойнов. По этой ссылке между прочим рекомендован дополнительный пакет, включающий ленивую загрузку. Но я предпочитаю явную.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас крупное реальное enterprise приложение, то да, иногда приходится писать весьма сложную логику запросов и не всегда даже linq'шных, а приходится писать крупные полотна чистого SQL.

Я не уверен, но мне кажется что вы не совсем правы насчёт того, что будут выполняться отдельные запросы -- потому что насколько я читал про core (сам не часто сталкивался на практике) иногда может делать JOIN а иногда и отдельный запрос. А вот EF6 как раз нагородит огромный, сложный но точно один запрос.

Варианты упрощения тут особо не просматриваются -- у всё include и then include.

Максимум -- можете попробовать перейти на ОРМ Dapper, что даст вам [возможность писать raw sql запросы в режиме multiple results](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multiple-results), иногда это оказывается полезнее, чем тащить громоздкий linq.

Я пробовал скрестить dapper с EF, [вполне получается](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend). Примеры с multiple results можете поискать не только в документации, но и на so бывает, вот например: [Как получить связанные сущности на даппере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832844/213987)

Answer (score 1):

Эванс в книге «Предметно-ориентированное проектирование» рекомендует опираться на понятие *агрегата*. Предполагается, что сущность-агрегат может содержать другие сущности, которые без неё не имеют смысла и не могут быть доступны.

Классический пример — сущность *Заказ* с вложенными *Позициями заказа*.

В то же время, если сущность должна быть доступна отдельно в каких-то сценариях, то она не может быть вложенной. Это отдельный агрегат.

Возможно, у вас эта ситуация. Возможно, сообщения (message) и пользователи (user) могут быть доступны вне контекста тикета (ticket).

В целом, несколько `Include` это вполне нормально, но у вас их как-то и правда много.

Comment: Эванс рассуждает в рамках DDD, что применимо далеко не к каждому проекту. Без контекста в вопросе вообще сложно что то сказать, но я из вашего ответа не понял вашу мысль, что вы хотели донести до автора? На что отвечает ваш ответ?

Comment: @tym32167, вы регулярно пытаетесь превратить SO в площадку для дискуссий. Если у вас есть свой ответ, вы просто его напишите. Готов обсудить правомерность вашего комментария с привлечением администрации сайта.

Comment: Это совершенно необоснованное и несправедливое обвинение в мой адрес. В своих комментариях я стараюсь быть предельно конкретным и сам не люблю безпредметных дискуссий. Если я пишу комментарий под ответом, то у меня есть для этого конкретная причина. В вашем ответе я не понял сути и спросил это напрямую. Вы совершенно не обязаны мне отвечать, вы даже можете просто попросить меня вам не писать, если вам мои комментарии доставляют неудобства. Вы можете призвать администрацию, но я не вижу в этом никакой необходимости. Мы с вами взрослые люди и способны договориться самостоятельно.